# Double integral - computing error

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm calculating $\iint \limits_{D} y \ dx dy$, where $D = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : 0 \leq x \leq 2, \ \   y\geq 0, \ \ y^2 \leq 2x, \ \ (x-1)^2 + y^2 \geq 1 \}  $.

From what I understood, this set $D$ looks like this (the shaded area):

[image: set D]

In other words, $D = [0, 2] \times \left [\sqrt{2x - x^2}, \sqrt{2x} \right]$.

I tried calculating this integral in the following way:

$\int \limits_{0}^{2} \left ( \int \limits_{\sqrt{2x-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2x}} y \ dy \right )dx = \\ = \frac{1}{2} \int \limits_{0}^{2} (2x - 2x + x^2) dx = \frac{4}{3}$

However, Wolfram Alpha says that the result of this is $-\frac{4}{3}$. Where did I make a mistake? Should I change the integration limits in the inner integral? If so, why?

Comment: You're correct! I used Maple quickly and it's indeed $\dfrac{4}{3}$

Comment: Clearly the answer is $> 0.$  Just to check to see if Wolfram alpha was acting screwy, I entered it there, and it returned  $\frac 43$  Perhaps one of your limits flipped when you put it into Wolfram.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%5B0+to+2%5D+int%5Bsqrt+(2x-x%5E2)to+sqrt+(2x)+%5D+y+dy+dx

Comment: @DougM it seems that you're right, my bad, thanks for help!

Comment: Yes 4/3 sounds more probable than -4/3 since the function y is positive everywhere and the limits are positive and ordered by size everywhere.